# View same statistics as "Local Area Connection" Status gui from command line

Tags: powershell, bandwidth, netstat

First time poster here.

I am trying to get the current bandwidth usage for Windows Server 2008R2 via command line.  I've tried netstat -e but this gives me very different numbers than the actual bytes that have been transferred.

The stats I'd like to see are the same stats that are shown when you click on "Local Area Connection" (or whatever your active internet connection is listed as) within the "Networking and Sharing Center" gui in Control Panel.  Within the gui window that comes up there is the lower "Activity" section.  The sent Sent and Received information is what I am trying to get via msdos or powershell.

Thanks to anyone who can lend a hand.

Comment: What version of Powershell are you using?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks for the response. I am using powershell v2.0

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade? v4 comes with a whole NetAdapter module that you would probably find very useful. Check out `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134956.aspx

Comment: @TheMadTechnician the NetAdapter module is specific to Windows 8.1/Server 2012R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to use `get-Counter`.

Here is the line that gives my network card bandwith usage :

```
get-counter "\\jpbhpp2\interface réseau(intel[r] 82567lm gigabit network connection)\total des octets/s"
```

But be careful you **CAN'T use it like that** because counters names are specific to the language of your system.

So you have to adapt it to your computer try :

```
get-counter
```

then

```
get-counter Get-counter -ListSet *
```

Comment: Thanks JPBlanc.  I've looked into Get-Counter and have come up with the following that will grab an hours worth of data Get-Counter "\\$HOSTNAME\$NIC_NAME\bytes total/sec" -SampleInterval 3600